# 'Self-aware' classes?

Tags: vb.net, oop, class, object

long time reader first time poster. Please be gentle.

I avidly create games in VB.net. Being a hobby programmer I give my games away for free. Since I'm a hobbiest without formal training I do try and educate myself on proper programming principles and follow them when programming such as OOP. There are however some things I have obviously missed being self-taught that perhaps I would know if I were formally educated.

Once such issue that has really been my bane is how different classes (from now on referred to as objects) 'know' about each other WITHOUT programming specific interaction (stay with me here... please...)

Okay imagine this, you have a space game and the following objects

- clsShip
- clsMissile
- clsAsteroid
- clsSpaceJunk

Now each one of these objects has a Health, X,Y and Z private members and properties that are all inherited from clsSpaceEntity for argument sake. Now one way of programming collision between them would be to code out the following logic in the main game loop

for each ship in a list of ships
check each clsMissile in a list to see if it collides with it and if so, reduce health
check each clsAsteroidin a list to see if it collides with it and if so, reduce health
check each clsSpaceJunka list to see if it collides with it and if so, reduce health
... and so on and so on for every object 
next

ect ect ect...

Now this might seam okay if your talking about the simple example above but some of my games have tens or even HUNDREDS of objects that interact in this basic way.

Now my question to the experienced programmers out there.

Is there a way in OOP to do the following...

for each thing that inherits from clsSpaceEntity
check against every other object that inherits this type (except itself) and if they   collide then reduce health
next

?

This sort of ability for a type of objects/class or whatever to be 'aware' of another and how they are the same/different and interact would save me tonnes and tonnes and TONNES of coding.

Any assistance/help or feedback on this would be very appreciated. Thank you for your time, sorry for the long read.

Comment: Don't use Hungarian Notation (`clsWhatever`).

Comment: It looks like you're trying to achieve proper separation of concerns.  Using some more OOP concepts, you can make beautifully separated logic without giant methods that handle every type of object.  Good luck!

Comment: Slightly off topic, but you seem a little confused about classes and objects. While they are related, they are not the same thing. This comment box is a bit small for a full explanation, but reading up on the differences would make life easier for you.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of having a separate `List(Of T)` for each derived object, you should make a single `List(Of SpaceEntity)` that holds all of your entities.

You can then make a nested `For Each` loop that loops through every pair of entities and does collision checking.  (after an `If x <> y` check)

You can further enhance your design by giving  `SpaceEntity` a `MustOverride` function to handle collisions with other objects, without polluting your collision loop with separate logic for each entity.
You should probably use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to allow entities to react differently to collisions with different other kinds of entities.

Note that each collision will be sent to both objects that collided separately; you need to handle that in your logic.

Answer (score 2):

If I was writing logic that dealt with a single ship, or single missile, asteroid, etc Then that logic should clearly belong in the respective class.

If I'm writing logic that deals with multiple objects or even worse, multiple objects of different types, I would tend to put that logic in a class that represents a higher level concept.

For example, you might have a Universe class that contains a collection of SpaceEntity's.  And there is a Universe.FindCollisions() that returns a collection of Collision objects.

```
public class Universe {
    private IEnumerable<SpaceEntity> _entities;

    public IEnumerable<Collision> FindCollisions() {
        foreach(var e1 in _entities) {
            foreach(var e2 in _entities) {
                if (e1.CollidesWith(e2)) {
                    yield return new Collision(e1, e2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another way to tackle it might be to have a CollisionCalculator class that accepts a collection of SpaceEntity's in its constructor and is the place where that specific logic lives.

```
public class CollisionCalculator {
    public IEnumerable<Collision> Collisions {get; set;}

    public CollisionCalculator(IEnumerable<SpaceEntity> entities) {
        // logic to build the Collisions collection goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: That nested foreach loop will be return two collisions for each overlapping pair of entities.  One for the missile colliding with the rock and one for the rock colliding with the missle.  You may need to filter these out, depending on how your collision resolution is handled.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the double nested for loop will become impractical as the number of objects gets large (over a few hundred).  If there's some distance between objects which will guarantee that they can't possibly collide, it may be helpful to subdivide the universe into blocks which are larger than that, and keep a list of the objects which are at least partially in each block.  Using simple partitioning in 3d space, some objects might have to appear in up to eight lists, but testing 100 groups of ten objects for collisions will be faster than testing one group of 1,000.

Comment: Incidentally, it's possible and not overly difficult to subdivide 3-dimensional space into regions such that no object would fall into more than four regions (rather than eight).  If rounding Y to the nearest integer would yield an odd number, add 0.5 to X.  If rounding Z to the nearest integer would yield an odd number, add 0.5 to both X and Y.  Then round all three coordinates to integers.  A mapping between spacial coordinates and XY values would show that space was divided into unit cubes placed so that no more than four would be within a quarter unit of any point.